# how to disable Eclipse content-assist semicolon insertion (with Android project) - unchecking doesn't work

Tags: android, eclipse

Is there any way to stop Eclipse (Helios) from automatically-inserting semicolons at the end of every line when working on an Android Java file? Or at least refrain from insidiously moving the cursor to the position before the semicolon when I type it myself?

I tried going to Window->Preferences->Java/Editor/Typing and un-checking "Automatically insert at correct position: Semicolons", but it was never even checked to begin with.

This behavior is driving me insane. I'll type the final semicolon at the end of the line, and the editor backs up the cursor so that when I hit return a moment later, the semicolon gets moved to the next line.

Comment: Seems not to happen with projects not having Android nature.   Also reported earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695454/how-to-disable-eclipse-content-assist-semicolon-insertion-with-android-project.

Answer (score 3):

Change **Auto activation triggers for Java** to `.(` in *Preferences/Java/Editor/Content Assist/Auto Activation*. The default for Android is `.` and that doesn't work for some reasons.

Comment: This is like three years late but make sure you restart Eclipse after changing this